# How to print object as part of a string and have firebug able to inspect it?

Tags: javascript, firebug

right now I use firebug to inspect objects I print occasionally, when I'm getting lazy in my debugging.  So if I am in an method and I want to inspect an object I can type:

```
console.log(object);
```

and In firebug I can inspect it, including expanding and collapsing keys within it as I feel, it's very covenient.

However, I'd now like to be able to include the object in part of a line.  So for instance maybe I want to do something like this:

```
const value = calculateValue(key);
console.log(`value for ${key} is ${value}`);
```

This doesn't do what I want.  I would get something like:

```
value for foo is ${object}
```

instead of value being something that firebug can inspect, expand, etc.

I can work around this with two lines:

```
console.log('value for key ${key}:');
console.log(value);
```

which works, but is kind of ugly, and in theory could be a problem if I were trying this while using promises/generators/sagas or any other threading logic.

is there a simple syntax to allow me to provide an object as part of a longer line and have firebug able to recognize it as an object to allow inspection of it?

Comment: if either of these worked please choose the accepted answer. If you're still having trouble please update.

Comment: Note that [Firebug is officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) and Firefox users are advised to use the [Firefox built-in DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/) instead.

Comment: @SebastianZartner your right.  I was using firefox built in dev tools all along, I'm just so use to referring to firebug I suppose I still call the built in tools, which have similar look and feel, firebug.  That was misleading on my part though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`console.dir(object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) so it prints to the browser, and it becomes inspectable by Firebug.

Obviously just use for development and delete from prod.

Comment: Who uses Firebug? :)

Comment: @epascarello I agree with the sentiment. Better tools out there. OP mentioned it, however.

Comment: @epascarello because I often work in areas with limited connectivity and I'm guaranteed to have firebug but not necessarily to have the other better tools.

Comment: @dsollen Um, Firebug is no longer maintained and consoles/debuggers are built into all modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

So use comma

```
console.log(`value for ${key} is`, value);
```

or JSON.stringify it

Comment: I don't think value should be surrounded by $() in your example ;)